# How can I make an element stick to the bottom of the page when scrolling up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is shown here: https://imgur.com/a/YFcfO3N

Basically I want a menu that sits at the bottom of the page and when you scroll up it sticks to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can you please share what code you have, what you have tried, etc?

Comment: `position:sticky;`

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look in the developer console at https://imgur.com/a/YFcfO3N and it seems, they use a container for the footer with the class "Footer-wrapper" with the following CSS attributes:

```
.Footer-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

When scrolling down, there is another class added to the container, "down":

```
.down {
    bottom: -60px;
}
```

The negative position must correspond to the height of the footer / menu.

I think, they're doing this with JavaScript. You can check whether the user is at the top of the page in JavaScript like this:

```
let userIsAtTheTopOfThePage = window.pageYOffset === 0;
```

The class can be added to the element like this:

```
element.classList.add("my-class");
```

and removed like this:

```
element.classList.remove("my-class");
```

EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood the question first, but what you want to achieve is possible in a similar way. Let's look at this example menu:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu item 1</li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
        <li>Menu item 3</li>
        <!-- Add more menu items here -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With this CSS

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.scrolling-menu {
    position: static !important;
}
```

and this JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
        var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var documentHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
        var scrollThreshold = documentHeight - windowHeight - 200; // Adjust this value to determine when the menu should become part of the flow

        if (scrollPosition > scrollThreshold) {
            menu.classList.add("scrolling-menu");
        } else {
            menu.classList.remove("scrolling-menu");
        }
    });
});
```

it should be possible.